# Xcode Scheme post script action shell Script not working.

Tags: xcode

[image: Script Location]

Added shell script in post actions, But that script is not executing when build the app. I don't want to add runscript in build phases. I want make it work from schemes.

I have given the permission to the folder also like

```
chmod u+x /Users/aaaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomProject-cnlrdyiazxefgvfxhnsvmwazjxix/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CustomProject.app/Script.sh

chmod u+x /Users/aaaa/Desktop/CustomProject/CustomProject
```

code inside the script is simple which contains echo statement as below.

```
echo "Executing Shell Script"
```

Comment: Have you tried by adding it in Project Settings >> Build Phases >> Run Script?

Comment: i think you have some syntax errors in your script. Have you tried debugging it? Can you maybe show the script?

Comment: i added simple echo "Statement" for demo, Nothing is there in script except one echo statement

Comment: I think you're missing the `.` before the script. It should be `./Users/.../Script.sh`